# Distinct a column using javascript in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

I have a database with multiple columns. I am trying to distinct a column so I may add the numbers of the second column. I am creating a new collection (table). 
For Example:

```
states     race  race_1  geo_type
Alabama    1     3       state
Alabama    4     1       state
Alabama    4     1       state
Alaska     5     1       state
Alaska     2     1       state
```

So the output should be.

```
states     race  race_1  geo_type
Alabama    9     5       state
Alaska     7     2       state
```

I am using Javascript to work on this.
Here is what I have so far:

```
db.race_collection.distinct('states').forEach(function(state_lookup){
var race_sum = 0;

db.race_collection.find({'states': state_lookup}).forEach(function(doc){
    if (doc['race']) {
    race_sum = race_sum + doc['race'];
    }
    if (doc['race'] != null)
        db.indicator_collection.insert({
        'race': race_sum,
            'state': state_lookup
})
})
})
```

I tried looking for an answer to this in Javascript but could not find anything close. I have not moved on to **"race_1"** yet because I couldn't even get **"race"** to add up. You may rip my code apart if needed. It's important that I use Javascript to work this out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework to get your desired result. Run the following aggregation pipeline, which will group all documents by the `states` key using **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** and calculates the totals for the other fields with the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** operator. Selecting the other field `geo_type` within the grouping is done with the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** operator.

Another pipeline stage [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) will replace the `_id` returned from the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline and adds the new field along with the other fields.

The documents returned by the aggregation pipeline are then written to another collection using the **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)** operator :

```
db.race_collection.aggregate([  
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$states",
            "race": { "$sum": "$race" },
            "race_1": { "$sum": "$race_1" },
            "geo_type": { "$first": "$geo_type" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "state": "$_id",
            "race": 1,
            "race_1": 1,
            "geo_type": 1
        }
    },
    { "$out": "indicator_collection" }
])
```

Comment: This worked and easy to handle. I have not used aggregation before. But, what if want to use **"states"** in place of **"_id"** for column name. It gives error 'state' must be defined as an expression in object. **"_id"** is a necessary.

Comment: In that case you will need another pipeline stage [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) just before the `$out` pipeline, this will replace the `_id` and adds the new field. Check my edit for implementing this.